# get the internet ip address

Tags: android, linux, ip

I need to get the internet ip address. For now i want to get it using the linux terminal, so i type "ifconfig". I'm connected by my android phone via thetering, and i've noticed there's not my internet ip address in the output of "ifconfig".

```
usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6a:22:38:4d:92:36  
          indirizzo inet:192.168.42.79  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Maschera:255.255.255.0
          indirizzo inet6: fe80::6822:38ff:fe4d:9236/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:31359 errors:4 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:4
          TX packets:27688 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisioni:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          Byte RX:30033107 (30.0 MB)  Byte TX:4855114 (4.8 MB)
```

This is the output of the command "ifconfig".
Is there a universal way to get the ip address, by script commands or by "c" functions?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Java snippet that might help:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
int ipAddress = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code to get IP address via Java code (whether its connected via 3G or WIFI)

```
public String getLocalIpAddress() {
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, ex.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Reference: [Get the ip address of your device](http://www.droidnova.com/get-the-ip-address-of-your-device,304.html)

If you want to get IP address in C, probably this thread would help:

[using C code to get same info as ifconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951257/using-c-code-to-get-same-info-as-ifconfig?rq=1)

Comment: Hi Chandra, can i get the internet ip address , not for device ip. if mobile is connected to wifi or 3g or 2g or anyway. mobile having internet means, need that internet ip address please..

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague. What sort of IP address are you looking for? If you're looking for your LAN IP, `ifconfig` or `iwconfig` will suffice. If you're looking for the WAN IP use

```
wget -qO- http://cmyip.com | grep "My IP Address Is"
```

and you should be able to see your IP. I don't know whether the Android terminal you're using supports `wget` but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

The IP address after "inet:" i.e. 192.168.42.79 IS your IP address.  But, that being said, the shortest python script is...

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(('google.com',80))
return s.getsockname()[0]
```