# How to find MTU value for UDP sockets

Tags: linux, sockets, udp, mtu

I am working on UDP socket programming, and I have to stop the transmission in application, if requested data is more than MTU value.

To achieve this I have to read MTU value but I don't know how to get MTU value (could be by using getsockopt()) in case of UDP sockets.

Is there any way to find the MTU value with UDP sockets?

Answer (score 0):

The `ifconfig` command is giving the MTU. By `strace`ing it I see that it uses `ioctl` (on some socket file descriptor) with `SIOCGIFMTU` to query the MTU

See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951257/using-c-code-to-get-same-info-as-ifconfig) (about getting in C code same info as `ifconfig`)

Answer (score 0):

In linux, it's not a UDP thing—it's an IP thing:

```
$ man 7 ip
```

It explains everything. You're looking for the `IP_MTU` socket option. It's pretty complicated, so you'll definitely want to read that man page. While you're at it, you should also `man udp` and `man 7 socket`.

It took me forever to figure this out, because it wasn't mentioned in `man sys_socket.h`!