# Get IP Address for a specific interface in OCaml

Tags: linux, ocaml, ip-address, nic

In the Core library there is the `Linux_ext.get_ipv4_address_for_interface` function which returns the IP address assigned to a specific network interface. Is there a simple way to do the same using only the standard library and without doing a `fork` to read the content of `ifconfig` or `ip addr show` ?

Comment: (I think the quick answer is no. The base OCaml language doesn't have this kind of low-level network API built in.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OCaml abstract machine doesn't include a notion of a network interface, so it is not possible to implement such behavior with the portable part of the OCaml standard library, without relying on OS-specific interfaces.

In fact, it is not even possible in C. As the interface is kernel specific, so in order to write such function, you will need to write a separate implementation for each Unix system, you're planning to target. [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951257/using-c-code-to-get-same-info-as-ifconfig), in C you will need to use `ioctl` interface, and use Linux kernel specific operations.

Good news is that you can still do it using OCaml. Although OCaml doesn't provide `ioctl` function, you can still call it via either [C Types](https://github.com/ocamllabs/ocaml-ctypes) foreign function interface or, directly, by [writing a stub function](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/intfc.html).

Comment: Sorry, instead of `Pervasive`, I meant all the modules of the standard library : no external library. I edit my question. Thanks for your answer