# Why NetworkInterface's methods throw SocketException

Tags: java, sockets, exception, network-programming, jvm

For example - [`public byte[] getHardwareAddress() throws SocketException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getHardwareAddress()).
The method returns the mac address of a network interface, but how is it related to sockets and ends up throwing [`SocketException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/SocketException.html)?

Comment: Because that's the any they designed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux `getHardwareAddress()` is implemented using [SIOCGIFHWADDR](http://linux.die.net/man/7/netdevice) ioctl request on a temporarily created datagram socket. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6052464/3448419).

Both `socket` and `ioctl` system calls may fail. The error will be translated to `SocketException`.