# reading and storing an adress Mac from the console

Tags: c, network-programming

I am a student, I am programming network practical work with the C language, my question is: how can I read MAC address (xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx) from the console, and store it in a table, I tried this but it isn't easy to manipulate them after.

Are there any better suggestions?

```
char MAC[18] = {""};
printf("\n\tEntrez l'@ Mac (XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX) en Hex :");
fgets(MAC,sizeof(MAC),stdin); //read MAC
```

Comment: You should take this question to a different forum as it directly violates the house rules of StackOverflow. Qu stipend posted here should be about particular problems you are trying to solve with a set of technologies and need help with.

Comment: Just about any programming language has tooling for network communications.

Comment: C also can be used.   ***[Look at this example.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1779758/645128)***   ***[Or, this one.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1780367/645128)***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly read the MAC address in hex from the user as shown, except for a small issue: giving `fgets` a buffer just large enough for the 17 characters and a final `'\0'` will cause the linefeed typed by the user to stay in the `stdin` stream.  It will be read before any further input, probably not what you would expect.

Furthermore, you want to convert this address into the binary format expected by the socket interface.

Give `fgets` a larger buffer, and parse with `sscanf`:

```
    char line[80];
    unsigned char MAC[6];

    printf("\n\tEntrez l'adresse Mac (XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX) en Hexa :");
    if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)
    &&  sscanf(line, "%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx",
               MAC, MAC+1, MAC+2, MAC+3, MAC+4, MAC+5) == 6) {
        // MAC address correctly parsed into MAC[0...5]
    } else {
        // invalid input.
    }
```