# MAC address of TBS6905 DVB-S2 Quad Tuner PCIe Card

Tags: c, linux, dvb, v4l

I have TBS6905 DVB-S2 PCIe card and its configured in Ubuntu 14.
And I have to find MAC address of all adapters because my application will do Blind Scan for all four adapters at the same time.

And index of these adapters will change after reboot.

So I have to find MAC address and set static start and end frequency to particular adapter device using C language.

What I tried:
 - I checked dmesg but I did get MAC address(while I have also Prof 7500 DVB-S2, in that dvb card I can find MAC address using dmesg). 
 - And I also checked udevadm command, but no luck yet.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get MAC address of your machine using a C program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779715/how-to-get-mac-address-of-your-machine-using-a-c-program)

Comment: I need MAC address of DVB card, not machine

Comment: What kind of interfaces does this card provide into the linux userspace? Video4Linux? Ethernet (virtual)?

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77170/how-to-bind-v4l2-usb-cameras-to-the-same-device-names-even-after-reboot

Comment: Its PCI card so its directly connected to mother-board
have a look, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qMKiLcRD4GU) fast-forward to 3:10

Comment: I guessed it was a PCIexpress card, due to the main subject. But what I asked about was what kind of interface you are provided with when you are inside Linux

Answer (score 0):

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147278/how-does-ubuntu-14-04-achieve-persistent-eth-interfaces

The persistent eth interface rule for udev, you can probably grab from another version or distro.

The MAC address is visible for shell scripts if you run commands like ifconfig.

Comment: I think **ifconfig** gives machine's MAC, not other hardware like DVB

Answer (score 0):

We can give static Index to particular DVB device using **udev** **rules**.

[Example1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/670197/udev-rules-targeting-every-usb-device) and 
[Example2](https://wiki.debian.org/udev)